# If $K\subset L$ and $L\subset M$ are normal, then $K\subset M$ is normal

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

Let $K\subset L\subset M$ be a tower of finite extensions.
If $K\subset L$ and $L\subset M$ are normal, then $K\subset M$ is normal. Is the statement true? If yes, give a proof and if not, give a counterexample.
Any hints? I still don't know whether it is true or not.

Comment: Have you tried some examples?

Comment: Yes, I think it should be true. But I am not sure how to prove it. I tried a counter example with $\mathbb{Q}\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})\subset \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},i)$, but the claim is certainly true. I started the proof as: $\forall \alpha\in M,f^{\alpha}_K$ splits completely in $M[X]$, and we also have that $f^{\alpha}_L|,f^{\alpha}_K\implies f^{\alpha}_K=f^{\alpha}_L\cdot h$. Am I right? If $f^{\alpha}_K$ splits completely, then $f^{\alpha}_L$ splits completely, but the reciprocal is not true.

Comment: @cut Actually, the statement is not true. If you think about it, there is no reason for it to be true. Hint: All you need is to change the largest field in your example.